# Unable to click login dropdown via xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am on trying to click the login dropdown, then the login button at this address using xpath, 
chrome found the xpath, but selenium will not find the element using xpath.
http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshh41eS9O96e7OKbAoA

Here is my code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//header[@id='main-nav']/nav[@class='nav nav-primary']//a[@role='menuitem']")).Click();
```

Why wont it locate the element using the `xpath` from chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *Selenium* opens the [*url*](http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshh41eS9O96e7OKbAoA) the *Login* dropdown is not within the [*Viewport*](https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css_rwd_viewport.asp) . To click the *login* dropdown you have to scroll the *login* dropdown *WebElement* within the [*Viewport*](https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css_rwd_viewport.asp) first then invoke `Click()` as follows :

```
var login_dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//header[@id='main-nav']/nav[@class='nav nav-primary']//a[@role='menuitem']"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", login_dropdown);
login_dropdown.Click();
```